# istanbul with mocha , nodejs always gives the same coverage

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I have setup istanbul to check the code coverage for my apis in node. I am confused if I got the whole idea if test coverage wrong. I have a directory sturcture as 
 -app containing
       -api
       -controllers
       -models
 -test 
    -api_test.js

running `istanbul cover _mocha` runs all the test cases in api_test.js   and returns the coverage as 
Statements   : 46.55% ( 27/58 )
Branches     : 0% ( 0/18 )
Functions    : 0% ( 0/13 )
Lines        : 48.21% ( 27/56 )

But then I remove a bunch of test cases , rerun istanbul still the coverage stastics is the same. 
According to my understanding of the tool it should give me statistics according to what all lines of code my test cases resulted in execution SO that should technically have reduced the test coverage when I run lesser number of tests. 
Also my report html only contains coverage stats of some models ( not even all of them ) So this adds to the confusion whether I have configured the test suite and istanbul correctly or not. Any help would be appreciated as I am quite new to node.

Comment: you have mocha and istanbul installed locally or globally ?

Comment: What happens if you run instanbul against an empty test suite, does it show 0% coverage? I don't think its unreasonable that removing a couple tests would still result in the same coverage.  If you choose a specific module, and remove all tests referencing that module (need to make sure that that module is not imported/used by other modules that do have tests) will test coverage results go down?

Comment: 0 passing (1ms)     @dm03514  I still get the same coverage stats.

Answer (score 0):

`istanbul` is for code coverage of source code files. `mocha` holds the test cases. You could have a single test case that accounts for 100% of your source code and istanbul would report 100%. You could add more test cases (for different paths, cases, etc), but istanbul would report the same because the first test case was at 100%.

I think you have everything set up correctly. In your question, you are reaching certain levels of coverage just by running your tests, which in turn load your source files. Having one test case or 100, the source files are still processed when loaded. You know you are not testing too much when you see things like this `Branches : 0% ( 0/18 ) Functions : 0% ( 0/13 )`, but still have some line coverage.

Istanbul will change its results when your test cases exercise more of the source code under test.

Answer (score -1):

@clay Thanks,  this helped. So what I have figured out now is that , in my case I have mocha tests which just call the api end points and get the results . So practically no source files are loaded when running the test cases and hence the code coverage practically never changes. I solved this by including the files I need to be covered on top of my test cases . This would be just a dummy require with only use to load up my source files for coverage. I can require files or folders , and all those source files will be watched and when executed would be added to report.
I hope this should be helpful for someone else facing similar confusions.